# A proper way of opening new wpf windows

Tags: c#, wpf, garbage-collection

I was wondering if there is a more efficient way of opening a fresh window in WPF than how presented in code below :

```
WindowConfigureDatabase windowConfigureDatabse;    

private void ButtonConfigureDatabase_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        if (windowConfigureDatabase == null)
        {
            windowConfigureDatabase = new WindowConfigureDatabase();
        }

        windowConfigureDatabase.Clear();
        windowConfigureDatabase.Show();
        windowConfigureDatabase.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
    }
```

Where windowConfigureDatabase is the new window I want to open. windowConfigureDatabase.Clear(); just resets all the values to default - there aren't many of them to reset. I was wondering whether or not this is the proper way of opening new windows in wpf. The other path I was thinking of was just simply creating a new window on each button click (that way I don't have to clear values each time...) but I'm afraid of allocating too much memory if a user opens the window and closes it a lot of times as I'm not quite sure if garbage collector picks the window up on OnClose event.

So basically my question is - does the garbage collector pick my windows up after I close them during Closing/Closed event? If not, what would be the proper way of managing the window's memory manually? Would adding a

> windowConfigureDatabase = null

on Closed/OnClosing event do well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> does the garbage collector pick my windows up after I close them
>   during Closing/Closed event?

Yes, if unreachable. Read up on [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973837.aspx) for a better idea.

> Would adding a
>
> > windowConfigureDatabase = null
>
> on Closed/OnClosing event do well?

Yes. Failing to do this will prevent the window from being garbage collected until `windowConfigureDatabase` is overwritten or the object containing it is collected.

The memory used by a window depends on its dimensions and how much memory it allocates to do what it needs to do. You generally don't need to worry about this unless you're creating tons of windows(~30+) and/or large volumes of data.

The fastest way to allocate is to allocate up front(ideally at startup) and reuse when possible. Fortunately with windows this is relatively easy. The idea is to hide instead of close, and only close when truly no longer needed.

Like this:

```
// In each window class or as a base class:
private bool isClosable = false;

protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs args)
{
    // Prevent closing until allowed.
    if (!isClosable) {
        args.Cancel = true;
        Hide();
    }
    base.OnClosing(args);
}

// Call this when you want to destroy the window like normal.
public void ForceClose()
{
    isClosable = true;
    Close();
}
```

Comment: This is really close to what I have in my code right now, except the DialogResult = false. I'm assuming you only need this if you have a button that is a default yes->exit button?

Comment: Setting DialogResult to false in this case is just a sane default. It's not necessary unless you require closing/hiding to have a cancel effect.

Comment: Alright. So I'm sticking with this but now I have to find a better way of setting the values back to default after closing a window than doing a separate function for each of them...

Comment: Since you're clearing when the window closes, it would be a good idea to put it in the OnClosing method of the `WindowConfigureDatabase` class. That has the same effect as if you called it in each of the close handlers.